# Geohash: How much hash length is enough

Tags: geohashing

For an application that needs to store Geographical location of a person in the form of Geohash, how much hash length (in characters) would be enough?

The code located [here](https://github.com/lyokato/libgeohash/blob/master/src/geohash.c) (referred in Wikipedia article on [Geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)) says:

```
    #define MAX_HASH_LENGTH 22
```

But they haven't mentioned any reason for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some justification can be found on other topics:

[geohash-and-max-distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836416/geohash-and-max-distance)

[geohash-string-length-and-accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448595/geohash-string-length-and-accuracy)

To localize a person, you would probably need a one-meter accuracy. 10 characters should be enough.

Comment: You mean 10 characters?

Comment: Yes its [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13836416/geohash-and-max-distance) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at something like building or house locations (associated with a person) you could go as small as geohash of length 8.

A geohash with a string value of 8 characters gets you to within +/- 20 meters of a location, a geohash of 9 characters gets you with +/- 5 meters.  See a full list of information on [geohash lengths on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash)